# Want to print the names which ends up with the letter "a" , Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

Basically i want to print the names which ends up with the letter "a", and count how many percentage those names are. I was trying some "charAt" stuff but i couldnt jump over it.

```
String[] array = new String[10];

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("ENTER THE NAMES");
String name = sc.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = sc.nextLine();
    if (name.length() < array[i].length()) {
        name = array[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("LONGEST NAME: " + name);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (name.length() > array[i].length()) {
        name = array[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("SHORTEST NAME: " + name);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (name.endsWith("a")) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't update the value of name to `array[i]`, so you basically loop over the same value ten times. This should solve it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    name = array[i];
    if (name.endsWith("a")) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to use array[i] instead of name (but as you use it more than once, it's better to use the first solution):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].endsWith("a")) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you realy need to loop three times offer the same array?
2. Try to use variables more often. Reminde that each `array[i]` is an access to the array same for `array[i].length()`
3. `name.endsWith("a")` is not right if you were looking at the names in the array for the loop it should be `array[i].endsWith("a")`

   ```
   String[] array = new String[10];

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("ENTER THE NAMES");
   String name = sc.nextLine();

   String shortest = name;
   String longest = name;

   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       array[i] = sc.nextLine();
       String currentName = array[i];
       int length = currentName.length();

       if (longest.length() < length) {
           longest = currentName;
       }
       if (shortest.length() > length) {
           shortest = currentName;
       }
       if (currentName.endsWith("a")) {
           System.out.println(currentName);
       }
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("LONGEST NAME: " + longest);
   System.out.println("SHORTEST NAME: " + shortest);
   ```